# Flutter setState() doesn't change

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, native

I have a problem regarding changing the state in a SearchDropdown object. The value it's not changed if an item is already selected. If I delete it, then I can change the state. I don't understand where the problem would be.

```
  @override
  void initState() {

    _dropdownPlatformReach =
        buildDropdownMenuItemsPlatformReach(_platformReach);
    _selectedPlatformReach = _dropdownPlatformReach[0].value;

    super.initState();
  }
```

```
Expanded(

                                  child: SearchableDropdown.single(
                                  isExpanded: true,
                                  value: _selectedPlatformReach,
                                  hint: " ",
                                  items: _dropdownPlatformReach,
                                  onChanged: (PlatformReach selectedPlatformReach) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _selectedPlatformReach = selectedPlatformReach;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                                flex: 2,
                              ),
```

```
class PlatformReach {
  String name;
  String hint;
  PlatformReach(this.name, this.hint);

  static List<PlatformReach> getPlatformReach() {
    return <PlatformReach>[
      PlatformReach('Jud Galati', '(RO, [Galati] County)'),
      PlatformReach('Jud Braila', '(RO, [Braila] County)'),
      PlatformReach('Jud Prahova', '(RO, [Ploiesti] County)'),
      PlatformReach('Jud Maramures', '(RO, [Baia Mare] County)'),
    ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

It seems that because I had another dropdown on the same page, the setState didn't changed for the other one.

I solved this by moving each dropdown widget in separate files.